# Script to add class="transition" to all links on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addition, transition

Is there anyway I can use a javascript code to add a class to EVERY link on a website?

The reason I am doing this is that I'm adding a fade in and fade out for all links that switch pages on my website, however I must add the class="transition" to all links on the site.

There has to be an easier way than editing all links. . .

Thanks guys!

Comment: Great, love sites that annoy by fading in and out. Makes users needlessly wait that much longer to see the page.

Comment: Thanks for the positive and constructive criticism! I didn't realize .25 of a second per page on a four page site aimed at entertainment would bother you personally so much, what the heck was I thinking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, you would simply do this (It should be fairly self-explanatory):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a').addClass("transition");
});
```

Although, if you can select all of the links to add a class, couldn't you just do the fade in/out on the link tag instead of the class?  I guess I'm trying to understand how you are doing your fading in and out.

Comment: Seems like that should work, however it doesn't.  I forgot to mention I'm using wordpress.

When I opened the source the script was in the head of everypage, however all links do not have the class of transition.  ??

Comment: hahahaah OK I just had to remove the class from the script. . brain dead, but your reply did help me understand how silly I was being. . gotta learn somehow, thanks!

Comment: You won't see the class in the source.  It is added to the DOM tree of the browser.  You would have to look in Firebug, or some other debugger.  The other thing I would add is that you have to do this after the document is loaded.  See edit.

Comment: Why not just do: `$("a").click(function(event){...`?

Comment: Yep Exactly - Been workin too many hours, just started with javascript two days ago, so pretty new to it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem!  I've coded some pretty awesome code late at night myself.  Speaking of which, I should go to bed...

Comment: @RobG: his code, not mine (he deleted his example code comment)  I was answering how you would do something for all links, not whether his UI model was correct.  :)